# Deploying Migrations using network 'rinkeby' - insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, truffle-migration

I'm connected to the "Rinkeby" network on MetaMask. I've imported the private key into Geth. Thereby, I unlocked the account using `geth --rpc --networkid 4 --unlock <account_address>`. Thereafter, I'm trying to deploy my smart contract using truffle. I'm using the following command to deploy the migrations: `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby --compile-all`. But I receive the following error -

> Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Inside truffle.js, I've configured to connect to Rinkeby as follows -

```
 host: "localhost", 
 port: 8545,
 from: "<account_address>",
 network_id: "4",
 gas: 4000000, 
 gasPrice: 20000000000
```

I have 3 ETH in my account from the Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet.

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Is you local node synced with the network? Did you check the balance from your node's console -> ``eth.getBalance(<account_address>)``?

Comment: @ivicaa
Based on your comments, I imported the address into the keystore (specified a new datadir), unlocked the account and started a local node. Within the console (`geth attach`), if I try running `eth.fromWei(eth.getBalance(<account_address>), "ether")`, I'm getting `Error: invalid address`.

Comment: Okay, @ivicaa, I was typing a wrong command. It should have been `web3.fromWei`. It returns 0. So you are saying that the local node needs to be synced with Rinkeby?

Comment: I would say yes, if you're not sending raw transactions. Did you try it after the sync?

Comment: Hey @ivicaa
I initialized the synchronization. Now I'm getting the following error: `Error: exceeds block gas limit`. The command `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(<account_address>), "ether")` returns 0.

Comment: Hi @ivicaa
Even `eth.getBlock("latest").number` returns 0. What am I missing? I used the following command to initialize the synchronization -
```geth --networkid=4 --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --syncmode=light --ethstats='Test:whatever@hello.com' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@171.79.83.3:30303?discport=30304 –-unlock=”<account_address>” –-password password.sec```

Comment: Sounds like two problems. 1/ check at https://rinkeby.etherscan.io that the address has funds at, 2/ how big are your contracts that you're trying to deploy? Did you try it on testrpc first? Btw. you can set gas to 7000000, the limit of the last block at rinkeby was 7,5M

Answer (score -2):

You would set your gas to 6712390 at truffle configuration. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried with `gas: 6712390` within truffle.js. This doesn't work.